# Bad SQL Grammar for Spring Webservice

Tags: sql, spring, web-services, soap, jdbc

A colleague and I are currently working on adding an endpoint to a current webservice.

We are using WebLogic7 for our JDBC Data Source Connection and SOAP-UI for our testing of Request/Response of the service.  I'm receiving the following error when submitting the soap call.

```
 <statusMessage>PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT XML_INFO FROM DATA.EVENT_STAMP WHERE FACT = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Descriptor index not valid.</statusMessage>
```

Here is what I have in my endPoint for the SQL call.  `<value><![CDATA[SELECT XML_INFO FROM DATA.EVENT_STAMP WHERE FACT = ?]]></value>`

I know this only has so much information but based on the error and SQL, does it look ok?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try google on 'java.sql.SQLException: Descriptor index not valid.'?

Comment: Yes it looks OK it is a perfectly normal SQL exception and not a web-service issue.